# How to use custom groupBy and LeftJoin in Laravel query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I tried this query:

```
 $this->data = \DB::table('months')->select(DB::raw("months.id, COUNT(clients.id) as total"))
            ->leftJoin('clients','months.id','=','MONTH(created_at)')
            ->groupBy('months.id')
            ->first();
```

It returns me an error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MONTH(created_at)' in 'on clause'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the table of your `created_at` column.

```
$this->data = \DB::table('months')->select(DB::raw("months.id, COUNT(clients.id) as total"))
            ->leftJoin('clients','months.id','=','MONTH(clients.created_at)')
            ->groupBy('months.id')
            ->first();
```

Comment: I need to use `DB::raw()` for `MONTH(clients.created_at)`